# How to select option if value is 'exactly' the string?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, forms

```html
<select>
    <option value="America">America</option>
    <option value="North America">North America</option>
</select>
```

We have an issue where in WP Forms we have a list of countries or regions, and we want to be able to disable any given one as a Parent, such as disabling "America" in the form above.  IE. Europe, Great Britain, Spain.  We'd like to disable Europe form being selected.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
(function( $ ) {
  'use strict';
  $(document).ready( function(){
    var $option = $('option:contains("America")');
    $option.attr('disabled',true);
  });
})(jQuery)
</script>
```

I tried this, as I found it online, but the issue is that for North America, this tool will be disabled as the option "contains" America.

Is there a different "contains" term to use, that means this "specifically and only" in the field....?

Comment: Use a type selector, and check the content of the value attribute, instead of the option's text content: `$('option[value=America]')`

Answer (score 0):

For your particular code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
(function( $ ) {
  'use strict';
  $(document).ready( function(){
    
    $(`option[value="${ CSS.escape('America') }"]`)
      .attr('disabled', true);
    
  });
})(jQuery)
</script>
```

But to disable several items I would use `jQuery::filter()`:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
(function( $ ) {
  'use strict';
  
  const blacklist = ['America', 'Europe'];
  
  $(document).ready( function(){
  
    $('option')
      .filter((_, option) => blacklist.includes($(option).attr('value')))
      .attr('disabled', true);
      
  });
})(jQuery)
</script>
```